# Visual Studio 2022 C# the cursor is right before the closing curly braces

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2022, indentation, curly-braces

I recently updated to VS Community 2022 (from VSC 2019).
After writing a method (or class) when I wrote the opening curly brace it looked like this:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

With the cursor being before the closing brace.

Before the update this is what happened: (which I would very much like to recreate):

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    //cursor here
}
```

I tried changing the settings in Tools->Options>Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Formatting->New Lines, but that only achieved this:

```
void SomeMethod(){
}
```

The cursor being before the closing brace like in the first case.

I read a very similar question to mine - the only difference being that they had a Mac and I have Windows. The "soluton" was a VS update but it does not seem to effect Windows users...

Comment: I'm using VS2022 version 17.7.0 and it works as expected, meaning with an empty line between thoses brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Enable option `Leave block on single line` .
The opening curly  brace would be like :

[image]

Then `enter`:

[image]